# hide scripts in msi installer

Tags: python, installation, windows-installer

I am creating an python based msi installer. 
by which I am executing some python scripts while the installer is running.
But I dont want to deliver/install these scripts with package just want to hide them in the msi and use while its running.  I tried using binary table in the msi for the same but it didn't work.  >How should i do it?

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be temporary files. You can store them in Binary table and use two custom actions:

- one which extracts them before the installation starts
- another one which removes them when installation is finished

You can extract them in a temporary location, for example the user Temp folder.

Comment: is it mandatory to extract them on local system? cant we have code directly executing from inside of msi?